# python write to csv with dictWriter

Tags: python-3.x, csv, filewriter

I am trying exactly the same code given in the example.

```
import csv

with open('names.csv', 'w') as csvfile:
    fieldnames = ['first_name', 'last_name']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)

    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Baked', 'last_name': 'Beans'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Lovely', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
    writer.writerow({'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'})
```

But instead i am using of

```
write.writerow(abc)
where I declared abc = {'first_name': 'Wonderful', 'last_name': 'Spam'}
```

It is failing in this case. Why is that so? What is the alternative. I cant type in all the fields as I have more that 100 columns. Also what is the efficient way to handle when there are more than 100 Columns and 1Million records to be inserted.

Comment: "It is failing in this case". Failing how?  See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: It is not writing the record. It is just writing header.

Comment: There is no difference between assigning a dictionary to a variable and writing it with the variable vs. spelling it out.  Really, read [mcve]. "I am trying exactly the same code given in the example" except you changed it.  Show exactly what you are trying, and any error messages.

Comment: Sorry about that. Give me a minute. I will check it in detail.